# Image couldn't be loaded from asset folder(No indentation problem)

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I created a new project using this command on the terminal:
`flutter create test_app`

Then, I created the assets folder and an images folder. I have added one image to this folder for testing.

test_app/assets/images/

test_app/assets/images/note.png

I have edited pubspec.yaml for the assets folder. (I made sure that there was no indentation related problem and I did as it says in the documentation.)

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Then, I added this line to a column that has some widgets in the main.dart file.

`Image(image: AssetImage('images/note.png')),`

I have done everything right but why it does not work I could not get it? I have done some projects in past, there was no problem. I have tried to create many projects to solve this problem but I couldn't do it.

```
Unable to load asset: images/note.png

...
...

Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "images/note.png")
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#e7b4d(), name: "images/note.png", scale: 1.0)
```

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021 darwin-x64,
    locale en-TR)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.52.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

I have tried the iOS simulator and Android Phone.

My computer is macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the full path of the image like this:

```
  Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/note.png')),
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is my bad. I have changed it as you say and it worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the image as well in the pubspec.yaml folder instead of just `assets/images/`. What I mean is as following:

```
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/image.png
```

That will work.